how to round corners of path line SwiftUI
when using the CGRect path how can I round the corners, is it possible to round out the bend so the change of the angel is not sharp?
struct Line: Shape {
    var angleHeight: CGFloat = 10
    var angledLength: CGFloat = 10

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        let startPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY)
        path.move(to: startPoint)
        let totalHorizontalLength = rect.width - angledLength
        let horizontalLengthBefore = totalHorizontalLength / 2
        let horizontalLengthAfter = totalHorizontalLength / 2
        let horizontalEndPoint = CGPoint(x: startPoint.x + horizontalLengthBefore, y: startPoint.y)
        path.addLine(to: horizontalEndPoint)
        let angleEndPoint = CGPoint(x: horizontalEndPoint.x + angledLength, y: horizontalEndPoint.y - angleHeight)
        path.addLine(to: angleEndPoint)
        let finalEndPoint = CGPoint(x: angleEndPoint.x + horizontalLengthAfter, y: angleEndPoint.y)
        path.addLine(to: finalEndPoint)
        return path
    }
}

I tried using an arch path but nothing seems to work

The dup linked by @Sweeper gives you the key information. But you might find this answer and this small package more helpful.  The package will round the corners of anyPath of straight lines (like the Path in your post), and the answer explains how the package works.
